# What is the meaning of the three options when creating a dataset in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a dataset in Azure data Factory and i have to choose one of the three options below can anyone explain what they mean?

Import schema: From connection/store , From sample file, none

Sincerely
Christian

Answer (score 1):

You sometimes need the schema of the datasets to map between a source and sink dataset (like in case of copy activity)
So to get the schema details, there are 2 ways:
a) from sample file (you can upload a sample format file)
b)directly from connection (meaning it would try getting the metadata from source directly like in case of SQL, get details of table schema by connecting to db)

[image]

MSFT Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-datasets-linked-services?tabs=data-factory

None option is when you dont need the schema for that dataset.(like in case if you need to use the dataset for some generic use cases like query option in lookup activity)